# ConnectionString will not pick up my database variable

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I have a mysql query that im trying to run to display on a datagridview.  My ConnectionString has a `serverName` variable but my code wont pick it up.

When the form loads, it actually picks up the serverName (coming from a textbox) but my fill_grid method doesn't pick up the serverName in the connstring.

```
static string serverName;
MySqlCommand command;
public static string connString = @"server=" + serverName + "; Database=database; username=username; password=password";

// this is the method
public void fill_grid(string query)
try
            {

                dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
                MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
                //myconn.Open();
                MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand(query, myconn);
                MySqlDataAdapter myAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                myAdapter.SelectCommand = mycommand;
                DataTable dTable = new DataTable();
                myAdapter.Fill(dTable);
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dTable;
                //myconn.Close();
            }
catch (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }


// this is my button
private void btnShowInfo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            string query = "select * from students";
            fill_grid(query);
    }
```

What am i doing wrong.  Thanks!

Comment: Where are you actually populating `serverName`? That code is not visible.

Comment: You should pick up serverName in the TextChanged event for your textbox, and then set connString with the text you've picked up. Right now your serverName is coming in empty because it is only picking it up when the app loads for the first time, in which case the textbox is empty or filled with whatever default value you have. To get serverName to update when text is changed you have to use an event listener

Answer (score 1):

Your static string variable connString is being initialised with the default value of serverName (any empty string) before you have set the value from the textbox.

You need to set the value of connString after you have "picked up" the value from the textbox. Possibly set it in fill_grid - assuming you have previously set serverName :

```
static string serverName;
MySqlCommand command;
public static string connString;

// this is the method
public void fill_grid(string query)
{
connString = @"server=" + serverName + "; Database=database; username=username; password=password";

try
{
....
....
```

Comment: Thanks @PaulF !.  That did it. Much appreciated.

Comment: Ĵošħ Williard's suggestion is also another way to go - but note that a TextChanged event occurs for every character typed. Changing connString to a property would also ensure that the returned value was updated every time you used it.